# how to extract values from below xml code using java?

Tags: java, xml, parsing

how to extract values from below xml code using java?
Here I want to extract to,from,body,thread values using java.
Here total code is condider as string.

```
<message to="-105608156545@chat.facebook.com/Smack" 
from="-105465454665906545@chat.facebook.com" 
type="chat">
<body>sai</body>
<thread>NNLWF1</thread>
<active xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates" />
</message>
```

Comment: Use google and search for java xml parsing keywords. You'll find your answer

Comment: String xml="<message>....</message>";code not present in the new file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String xmlString="<message>....</message>";//above xml code
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance( message.class );
Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
message o =(message) u.unmarshal( new StreamSource( new StringReader(xmlString ) ) );
System.out.println("------getTo-------"+o.getTo());
System.out.println("------getFrom-------"+o.getFrom());
System.out.println("------getBody-------"+o.getBody()); 
System.out.println("------getThread-------"+o.getThread());
```

---

And Bean class(message) code.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class message {



    public message(){}

    private String to;

    @XmlAttribute 
    public String getTo() {
        return to;
    }



    public void setTo(String to) {
        this.to = to;
    }


    @XmlAttribute 
    public String getFrom() {
        return from;
    }



    public void setFrom(String from) {
        this.from = from;
    }


    @XmlElement  
    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }



    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }


    @XmlElement  
    public String getThread() {
        return thread;
    }



    public void setThread(String thread) {this.thread = thread;
    }
private String from;
    private String body;
    private String thread;



    public message(String to, String from, String body,String thread ){  
        super();  
        this.to = to;  
        this.from = from;  
        this.body = body;
        this.thread = thread;

    }  

}
```

Comment: +1 for an interesting idea and generation of a POJO. A link to the JAXB tutorial might not go astray either ;)

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to use Java's in built XPath capabailities, for example...

```
try {
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = db.parse(new File("Test.xml"));

    XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    XPathExpression expression = xPath.compile("/message[@from]");
    Node node = (Node)expression.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODE);
    System.out.println("From: " + node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("from").getNodeValue());

    expression = xPath.compile("/message/body");
    node = (Node)expression.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODE);
    System.out.println("Body: " + node.getTextContent());

    expression = xPath.compile("/message/thread");
    node = (Node)expression.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODE);
    System.out.println("Thread: " + node.getTextContent());
} catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException | DOMException | XPathExpressionException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

Which outputs...

```
From: -105465454665906545@chat.facebook.com
Body: sai
Thread: NNLWF1
```

Take a look at:

- [Java API for XML Processing (JAXP)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/)
- [XPath Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/)
- [How To Parse XML File Using XPath In Java](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-xml-xpath-tutorial-parse-xml/) as an example

For more details

Answer (score 0):

One way you can read your XML in java is:

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = db.parse(new File("yourFile.xml"));
        NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("message");
        for(int x=0,size= nodeList.getLength(); x<size; x++) {
            System.out.println(nodeList.item(x).getAttributes().getNamedItem("to").getNodeValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: In that case, you wont be extracting "to" or "from" or you can just put a check if the tag is present, then proceed for fetching attributes else just fetch body by tagName---- If this is what you asked and I understood.

Answer (score 0):

Here a complete example using a [data projection library](http://xmlbeam.org):

```
public class DataProjection {

    public interface Message {
        @XBRead("/message/@to")
        String getTo();

        @XBRead("/message/@from")
        String getFrom();

        @XBRead("/message/body")
        String getBody();

        @XBRead("/message/thread")
        String getThread();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String xml="<message to=\"-105608156545@chat.facebook.com/Smack\" \n" + 
                "from=\"-105465454665906545@chat.facebook.com\" \n" + 
                "type=\"chat\">\n" + 
                "<body>sai</body>\n" + 
                "<thread>NNLWF1</thread>\n" + 
                "<active xmlns=\"http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates\" />\n" + 
                "</message>";

        Message message = new XBProjector().projectXMLString(xml, Message.class);

        System.out.println(message.getFrom());
        System.out.println(message.getTo());
        System.out.println(message.getBody());
        System.out.println(message.getThread());

    }
```

This program prints out:

```
-105465454665906545@chat.facebook.com
-105608156545@chat.facebook.com/Smack
sai
NNLWF1
```